# Multiple WCF service calls in ACID transaction

Tags: wcf, acid

Here's my scenario: I need to make three or four calls to different WCF services before completing the transaction - what are my options, if any?

```
ServiceA.SaveWork(work1);
ServiceB.SaveWork(work2);
ServiceC.SaveWork(work3);
ServiceD.SendNotification(notification);
```

If one call fails, all fail... Note that these services may not be in the same domain.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to wrap those into a [System.Transctions.TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) to achieve this:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   ServiceA.SaveWork(work1);
   ServiceB.SaveWork(work2);
   ServiceC.SaveWork(work3);
   ServiceD.SendNotification(notification);

   scope.Complete();
}
```

Of course, you need to make sure your WCF services don't explicitly prevent being part of a transaction! (check out the TransactionFlow attribute - avoid the TransactionFlow.NotAllowed setting!)

Comment: That would involve the MSDTC, wouldn't it? If so...be prepared for a lot of pain in the hole....

Comment: @Alex: if it deals with multiple resources, yes. Granted, DTC is a pain, but often the only viable solution - that or no transaction support at all...

Answer (score 1):

If these services are all on different machines etc, using two phase commit will lead to lots of real world problems.

Therefore I don’t think transactions are a good solution....

I think you need to make all your services so you can undo the work if needed to recover from an error. Undoing a item of work can be very complex in the real world.

E.g If you need to book a car and a hotel and then the hotel burns down, you can’t expect to be able to un-book the car without losing some money.

However if all the services sit on top of the *same* database, then transactions may work well for you.

Comment: @Ian: can you say which problems you're expecting?

Comment: I'd love to know what are those real world problems, but yes, all the services sit on top of the same DB.

Comment: @John, e.g the IT person that runs ServiceB in the USA office restores a database at a different time to the IT person that runs ServiceC for a different company that is based in the UK.

Comment: @Ian: what's that have to do with transactions? That's more of a competence issue than a transactions issue.

Comment: @John, But the system design has to cope with the **real world**, in the real world you get lots of "competence issue" as soon as you do anything that makes use of services that are not all controled by a single person.

Comment: @Ian: most places I've worked handle the kind of issue you're describing by putting good procedures in place and by firing staff who violate such procedures. I also don't believe the issue ou're describing is a real one. Certainly, I've never heard of it in over 30 years in the industry.

Comment: Everything aside, I think adding the "Undo" method to the service will face the same problem - what if something goes wrong during ServiceA.UndoWork(work)?

Comment: You could implement transactional work in the services as resources that receive notifications on DTC work with IEnlistmentNotification...